# How to delete a plugin in Linux?

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04

I think I messed up a python plugin (moviepy) when I was trying to give myself write access. How can I either reinstall or delete the plugin from the terminal?

This is the location of the plugin

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy
```

Comment: `pip uninstall moviepy` if you have used pip, or `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy` if `pip` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used pip to install the plugin, use `pip uninstall moviepy` to uninstall it. If you do not wish to remove it and just reinstall it, use `pip install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall moviepy`.

`--upgrade` to get the latest version through pip, `--no-deps` without installing dependencies (assuming you haven't messed up the dependencies) and `--force-reinstall` to well, reinstall it.

Answer (score 2):

As @J0HN mentioned as a comment the best way is either :

> pip uninstall moviepy if you have used pip

or

> sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy if pip fails

Comment: Thanks, uninstalling seemed to work but when I try and reinstall with pip3 install moviepy I get an error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/moviepy': Permission denied

Comment: I put sudo in front and it seems to have worked. Thanks.